# Get Range of Cells Value as Display using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: excel-interop

I am programming with C# to access data from a range of cells in Excel Spreadsheet.

I can use the following code to access and return the values of range of cells into an object array.

`(object[,])Mysheet.UsedRange.get_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);`

However, I like to find a mean to return all data as strings (exactly as shown on the spreadsheet) into a string array or putting the values as text into the object array. Are there any mechanism to do that>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `.Text` in the `Range` object? As far as I know, you will have to iterate over each cell and do it for each of them.

Note that .Text is considerably heavy in terms of performance compared to `Value` or `Value2`.

And also note that it is also tricky, `.Text` returns the text as you would see it if you had Excel visible, so if you have a huge number in a column with a short width what `.Text` will give you is a lot of `####`

Sadly I can't think of another way to get it. Usually I get the raw values and format them properly once a get them all, but that assumes that I know which format is used in which cells.

Comment: You know a way of converting an Excel NumberFormat string to an equivalent C# string format string?